# App Service built-in Google Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, google-authentication, azure-authentication

I am a just beginning web developer (or really CS person in general) and have created a web app with Azure App Service and Node/Express. I just set up Google Authentication using this link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-google and I very simply made a display page with the option to log in with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-customize-sign-in-out#use-multiple-sign-in-providers

As far as I am aware, all of this works. However, I have absolutely no idea how to proceed from this point. I have looked at all sorts of docs, but nothing seems to work with my setup. I think what I need to do is get some sort of token, right? How do I get a token from where I am at? For perspective, the next thing I want to do is somehow link the login with a username. I know this will involve a database, but I haven't set up one of those yet as I didn't want to set it up in a way that the token doesn't work

Comment: A relevant microsoft documentation article would be a great answer. I dont think one exists, but I could be wrong

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-oauth-tokens#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code says "From your client code (such as a mobile app or in-browser JavaScript), send an HTTP GET request to /.auth/me (token store must be enabled). The returned JSON has the provider-specific tokens.". Is this my next step? Ive gone down quite a few wrong paths lately and am afraid of doing it again

Comment: The above part was indeed my next step

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and configured Google authentication and was able to sign-in the user successfully:***

[image]

**Make note of the App service URL like below:**

[image]

**Make sure to register the application in Azure Active Directory by adding the URI of App service like below:**

[image]

**You can make use of Azure Active Directory and add the users like below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> New user -> Create new user*

[image]

***If still the issue persists, you can make use of this [***blog***](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).***

For more in detail, you can **refer** below links:

[Azure App Services – Authentication with FB, Google and others in 5 minutes or so – Hryniewski.NET](https://hryniewski.net/2017/04/20/azure-app-services-authentication-with-fb-google-and-others-in-5-minutes-or-so/)

[How To Secure Your Azure App Service With Google Authentication (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-secure-your-azure-app-service-with-google-authentication/)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed response! Unfortunately it appears as if I was not clear enough. I have done all of this successfully. However, despite "signing in" the user, there are no changes on my site to reflect the individual user. What is my next step to make that happen?

Comment: @AuWiMo Depending on what you want to do, you can either [use the token store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#token-store) (you'll need to enable it from the App Service configuration) or the HTTP Headers injected by Azure (X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL, etc.). They contain everything you need to retrieve user information.